# New GCM Implemented, But Not starting App

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Trying to implement GCM in my app. Compiled successfully. But when i run my app, Its crashing. Stack trace :

> E/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
>                                                                         java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
>                                                                             at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
>                                                                             at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5174)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4769)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4709)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1415)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/app/sun.way2online.dropxapp-2/base.apk)
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzeC(Unknown Source)
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                             at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748) 
>                                                                             at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723) 
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5174) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4769) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4709) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1415) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
>   07-05 12:01:28.476 15753-15753/sun.way2online.dropxapp D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.

And

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd' appears in /data/app/sun.way2online.dropxapp-2/base.apk)
>                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzeC(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                at myapp.com.Services.RegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(RegistrationIntentService.java:29)
>                                                                                at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

My gradle file :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0"

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: have you added google-plauservices.json??

Comment: do you still experiencing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might comes from one of the libraries your app depends on, library that depends itself on Google Play Services as well. You might using an older version of the [Google Play Services SDK](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) and its still relies on the fact that [Google API Client](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient) class is an interface. This breaks backward compatibility because of the transitive dependencies of libraries. Please check if you use the latest version or remove the dependecy if possible.

For more information regarding Google Play Services, check this link: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/3mehbb/breaking_changes_in_google_play_services_81/

Comment: Thank you for reply